# Why is the code not reassigning the class to the id'ed tag but breaking instead?

Tags: javascript, css, class, drop-down-menu

Could someone please give me a hand with the below issue?

I have got a simple drop down menu with 3 options and would like to remove a "hidden" class (simple CSS with display: none) allocated by default to a div when option 3 (with a value of RU) is chosen but RE-ADD / leave the class when option 1 or 2 are chosen (again).

The HTML for the hidden div is like this :

```
<div class="hidden" id="cityRestrictions">
    <label for="cityQuery">Please select the city you were calling from: </label>
    <select id="cityQuery"> 
        <option value="Moscow"> Moscow </option>
        <option value="StPetersburg"> Saint Petersburg </option>
        <option value="Other"> Other </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

My javascript is as follows:

```
dialInLocation.addEventListener("change", function() {
    let location = document.getElementById('dialInLocation');
    if(location.value == "RU") {
        removeActivityItem();
    }
});

function removeActivityItem() {
    cityRestrictions = cityRestrictions.removeAttribute("class");
}
```

this works fine. If i choose the option with the value RU in the drop down, the class hidden is removed from the div and the content is displayed. 
However if i add an

```
if(location.value == "RU") {
    removeActivityItem();
} else {
    addActivityItem();
}
```

with addActivityItem defined as :

```
function addActivityItem() {
    cityRestrictions = cityRestrictions.setAttribute("class","hidden");
}
```

Then my code is completely broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if `cityRestrictions` is an element then you don't need to type `cityRestrictions = cityRestrictions.setAttribute("class","hidden")` because you can just type `cityRestrictions.setAttribute("class","hidden");`

Second of all, instead of adding the class and taking it away, I recommend changing the style by using `cityRestrictions.style.display = "none";` and `cityRestrictions.style.display = "block";`